# Media consent form for summer camp

Tags: copyright, privacy, photography, right-of-publicity, waivers

We have a media consent form that parents have signed for the campers at our summer camp.  The wording is as follows:

> The Participant identified below desires to participate in the [insert summer camp name] (“Activity”). This consent is mandatory to participate in the Activity.
>
> The Participant and their legal Parent/Guardian understand that photographs, videotapes, and other recordings will be made of participants in the Activity, including the Participant. The Participant and their legal Parent/Guardian consent to those photographs, videotapes, and other recordings and the use thereof as part of a record of the Activity and to promote the [insert team name].

My interpretation would be that we could only use the photos on promotional materials such as our website or flyers.  We wanted to send some photos out to parents (these photos would contain other campers), but since we have no control over what they are going to do, we are hesitant to do so.

Location is California (Bay Area)

**Given that we have permission to make recordings of campers, and to use those to promote the summer camp, are there any legal risks or constraints in sending such recordings to parents of campers since we have no control of their actions with these recordings?**

Comment: Not a lawyer. Personal anecdote from California, my kids' preschool had us sign a photography/media waiver like yours. At a birthday party, I was warned to be careful taking photos of other children because I didn't have permission of the other parents.

Comment: Could you state a clear question?  As best I can tell it is, "Given that we have permission to make recordings of campers, and to use those to promote [something], are there any legal risks or constraints in sending such recordings to parents of campers?"

Comment: Or possibly more clear... Given we have permission to posses and use such media, would that permission extend to also include distribution of the media to other parents?

Comment: The waiver strikes me as a moneymaking scheme for the legal profession. What negative consequences could result from sending photographs to children's parents? What potential harmful actions on their part are you worried about?